# Running GCC preprocessor -fdirectives-only *without* implicit -dD

Tags: gcc, preprocessor

Basically, I want to do what the title says.

I have some mildly complex header files, and I want to generate a single header file I can release as the public interface of a DLL.

I'm generating the header file as follows:

```
${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fdirectives-only -P \
  -E ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dll_header_base.h -o generated_public_header.h
```

If I run the compiler without `-fdirectives-only`, the precompiler is *much* more aggressive about stripping out contents of the header. The output of `-fdirectives-only` is *almost* what I want, but that particular flag forces the `-dD` flag on as well, which prepends all the compiler-defined macros to the generated header (450 lines of them!).

I don't really understand why `-fdirectives-only` forces `-dD` in the first place, and for my case, the later flag basically makes it useless. Looking at the options for `-dLETTER`, there also seems to be no way to turn it off.

How do I extract the directives-only preprocessed output *without* all the additional cruft?

---

Yes, I could pretty easily solve this with command line tools, but I want to keep the solution entirely constrained to the compiler/CMAKE. Eventually, I'd like to also support building on windows.